# UILabel not refreshing in UITableViewCell when reloaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I add two `UILabels` to a `UITableViewCell` and then name and number labels to that cell. When I reload the data in the `UITableView` (whether I add or delete a contact from the table view) the data in the labels are overlapping which means it's not reloading the labels, until the entire view is reloaded.

Can anyone please help?

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UILabel *name;
    UILabel *number;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        //NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        //      NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
        //      [sortDescriptor release];
    }
    CGRect Label1Frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 140, 25);
    name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label1Frame];
    name.tag = 1;
    [name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:name];

    CGRect Label2Frame = CGRectMake(150, 10, 140, 25);
    number = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label2Frame];
    number.tag = 1;
    [number setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:number];

    name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    number.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[phonenumbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [name release];
    [number release];
    return cell;    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should move your label creation code inside the cell initialization and then just reference them later by tag like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";        

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        //NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        //      NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
        //      [sortDescriptor release];
        CGRect Label1Frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 140, 25);
        UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label1Frame];
        name.tag = 1;
        [name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:name];
        [name release];

        CGRect Label2Frame = CGRectMake(150, 10, 140, 25);
        UILabel *number = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label2Frame];
        number.tag = 2;
        [number setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:number];
        [number release];
    }

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *numberLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    number.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[phonenumbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;    
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Saved me a good few hours at least (after wasting a good few hours trying to sort it out...).  In my situation I was declaring the UILabels (and buttons) ahead of the `if (cell == nil)` test and then adding to the cell within that test.  That didn't work, so I'm so pleased to have found this :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not re-using your UITableViewCell objects correctly, you only need to allocate and setup your UILabel objects once per cell that needs to be created. If a cell does already exist and can be re-used then you just need to retrieve the desired UILabel objects and modify the text property for each:

I suggest reading the following:

[UITableView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: your code will fail and cause memory leaks. The second cell will not have the name or number labels allocated to anything as you only set these in the cell initialization, you also never release these labels at all. The OP was also not releasing the text properties of the UILabels but the UILabels themselves.

Comment: Apologies @theChrisKent, absolutely correct, I misread the question. Edited and your correct answer voted for.

Comment: no worries, we've all done it. I figured it was something like that which is why you received no downvote from me. We're all just trying to help, thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: @theChrisKent, definitely, thanks for the understanding and restraint from the down-vote button ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do it is create custom table view cells and only set the label values in  the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method.
That ensures the most efficient use and reuse of `UITableViewCell`s.